# Reinstalling Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-8, installation, windows-10-desktop

So I took my laptop (a Lenovo Yoga 2 pro) in to best buy after it had water spilled on it. They said they'd fix it under warranty and I left it with them. A few days later I came to pick it up, but with only one problem. I gave them the laptop with windows ten as it was installed during the free upgrade period. I got the laptop back with windows 8. Best buy basically said tough titties and told me they couldn't do anything. Would I be able to install windows 10 to it with no problem, or would I have to buy a copy. I heard you can install it and use the windows 8 key it came with.
What does everyone think?

Comment: This is offtopic for Stackoverflow. I think you should contact Microsoft Support or ask the question in a windows related forum.

Comment: It would easier to put this question to a microsoft realted stackexchange, however this is not possible

Comment: if windows 10 was activated on a system you can later reinstall Win10 and Windows gets activated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I know, you can activate and install Windows 10 with the key of your old Windows version only if it's the one with which you upgraded to Windows 10. However it could be also possible to use other keys according to this link. Here is also shown how to reinstall Windows 10.

[How to reinstall Windows 10 with your old Windows 7/8/8.1 key](http://www.howtogeek.com/266072/you-can-still-get-windows-10-for-free-with-a-windows-7-8-or-8.1-key/)

Anyway because it's Windows 10 you also have a digital license which is linked with your account. So it's also possible to reinstall Windows 10 without a product key requiring only to log in with your Microsoft account. You can read yourself, just scroll to the section where it's about how to activate after reinstallation.

[How to: Windows 10 activation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440/windows-10-activation)